# Django Admin Sidebar Bug

Tags: python, css, django, admin

I've been having this weird issue with my Django site for a few weeks now that I can't quite figure out.

Whenever I go to the admin page on my local machine (DEBUG=True) it's completely unusable because the sidebar is filling the entire screen as pictured below:

[image]

This began happening when I upgraded to Django 3.1 if that matters (this project started on 2.1)

This does not happen on my live/production site. When I switch DEBUG=False on my local machine it works as expected as well however I can't figure out for the life of me what's causing this. I've tried other browsers as well to no avail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your projects' root urls.py file, simply add the below code to disable the new sidebar feature.

```
from django.contrib import admin

admin.autodiscover()
admin.site.enable_nav_sidebar = False
```

Thanks to The Go company from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63286591/django-3-1-admin-page-appearance-issue#_=_).