# Django admin view design error/acting funny

Tags: django, django-views, django-admin, django-admin-filters, django-admin-tools

[image]

Anyone faced this before? I have never. I installed Django 3.1 along with Python 3.9 and started facing this(see the image). Even when I scroll up, the top half stays there, its fixed, only the bottom half scrolls.
I am using ckeditor for the body field in my app. Could that package be the reason?

Comment: Can you check the console? Maybe there are some javascript errors

Comment: No. Nothing in the console. Its clean. Also I tried removing the ckeditor, but the problem persists.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63492729/12806577 Here. I found a link to a solution which worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Ckeditor can cause problems with django when working with code snippets. It needs to be configured.

Comment: How do I fix it ? Any alternative to ckeditor ? I tried tinymce and found ckeditor much better.

Comment: In Django, ckeditor and codesnippet can cause problems when used together. The following way can be followed to solve this situation: (settings.py)

CKEDITOR_CONFIGS = {
    'awesome_ckeditor': {
        'toolbar': 'Basic', 'allowedContent':True,
    },
}